# "This app can't run on your PC" But I don't know which app it's referring to

Tags: windows-10

I have a big, complex build process that is failing after producing the standard Windows 10 "This app can't run on your PC" message.

This is almost certainly caused by an earlier part of the process producing a bad .exe file, but I don't know which file and unfortunately the build tools I use (IBM ClearCase omake; not by choice) don't make finding what it's trying to run in any way easy.

Is there any way to get Windows to tell me *which executable* it's complaining about? I've checked the event viewer, I've tried using Process Explorer to find the owner of the error message (it's cmd.exe, presumably Windows displays the error in the parent process of the incompatible/corrupt .exe), but no luck. Surely there some way to identify the culprit?

Comment: Yes, look in the Windows EventViewer. I don't know exactly what event it is, but once you find it, it will tell you what the program is that it complained about.